# Secure encrypt-then-sign with RSA

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, signature

I understand that when you want to encrypt and sign data with RSA the generally recommended approach is sign-then-encrypt.

However, I have encrypted data that I need to sign, to prove the author of the encrypted data.

1. Encrypt wth recipient's public key
2. Sign with author's private key
3. Concatenate cipher text with signature

From reading papers such as [this](http://world.std.com/~dtd/sign_encrypt/sign_encrypt7.html), it seems that the problems with sign-then-encrypt are quite subtle, but solutions are quite straightforwrd.

I haven't been able to turn up much on issues with encrypt-then-sign. I guess one problem is that someone could simply strip off the signature and replace it with their own. My first thought was to prefix the data with the author's public key before encrypting, but then the signature can only 'really' be verified by the recipient (public verification is more desirable for me).

What are the issues associated with encrypt-then-sign, and what solutions exist?

** **Edit** **

I thought of another potential solution to the problem of someone replacing the original signature with their own - using X.509 certificates. So in step 3 above we also concatenate the certificate of the author. When verifying the signature we check that the public key matches that of the certificate, and we also verify that the certificate was issued by a particular, trusted CA. With this scheme, not just anyone can replace the signature, only those who are issued a certificate from the trusted CA. Any issues with this approach?

Comment: Another problem is that the recipient's public key needs to go into what's signed. $\hspace{1.32 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer I mention that in my question as a possible solution to the problem of someone replacing the signature

Comment: I see where you mention putting the _author's_ public key into what's encrypted, $\hspace{1.62 in}$ but I don't see where you mentioned what I said. $\:$

Comment: @RickyDemer sorry, I mis-read your comment - BTW, what is going on with the formatting of your last comment?

Comment: That's my attempt at making the lines have approximately the same length.

Comment: I prefer sign then authenticated encrypt. The only tricky part is including enough information in the signed part - it needs to be able to stand for itself.

Comment: "sign then authenticated encrypt", aka sign-encrypt-sign, since the encryption is public key. $\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer No, I mean sign, then authenticated symmetric encryption together with RSA encryption on the symmetric key. The authenticated part of that is mainly to prevent annoyances that could break the confidentiality. (padding oracles etc.)

Comment: @MurrayA: $\:$ Could you be more precise about what you mean by 'really' publicly verifiable? $\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer anyone with the author's public key should be able to verify that the signature was added by the author

Comment: Your original idea already achieves that. $\:$

Comment: @RickyDemer well, yes, but then there is the problem of anyone being able to replace the signature :/

Comment: The issues with your original approach and your most recent approach are that neither of them prevents surreptitious forwarding. $\:$ To address that, the sender's public key should be associated data for the symmetric AEAD. $\;\;$

Comment: After fixing that, there's still the issue of, even if the PKE is CCA2-secure, there's not necessarily a secure way for the receiver to non-interactively convince anyone else of what the plaintext on a signed message was. $\:$ (If the PKE does not have perfect completeness, then there's not necessarily _any_ way for the receiver to convince anyone else of what the plaintext on a signed message was.) $\:$ To address that, you should use sign-encrypt-sign, with the recipient's public key going into what's signed both times. $\;\;$

Answer (score 6):

The primary problem with encrypt-then-sign (signing the ciphertext) relates to the difference between signing for the purpose of assigning responsibility vs for the purpose of taking credit.  Encrypt-then-sign is OK for the former but not for the latter.  The issue is quite subtle.

In particular, in your protocol, the recipient has no reason to believe the sender (signer) was ever aware of the contents of the plaintext.  The signer must have been aware of the contents of the ciphertext and approved signing the ciphertext, but this does not mean that the signer knows or created the original message.

For instance, suppose we're using this to log into a site.  Suppose Alice, who is a system administrator, is going to authenticate to Sam, who is a server.  Suppose that, to authenticate, Alice is going to use your scheme to send a copy of the root password to Sam (encrypted and then signed); if everything checks out, Sam will conclude that Alice knows the root password and should be granted full access to the server.  Sounds reasonable, right?  But now look what can go wrong.  Mallet can intercept Alice's encrypted-and-then-signed packet, strip off Alice's signature, append her own signature, and forward it to Sam.  Sam will receive it and everything will check out: Sam can see that this was signed by Mallet and decrypts to contain the correct root password, so Sam will conclude that Mallet should be granted full access to the server.  That's bad.

The reason why an attack is possible in the latter example is that Alice and Sam were using the signature as a basis for taking credit: Alice was trying to take credit for knowledge of the root password, and Sam was willing to accept the signature as evidence for that.  However, encrypt-then-sign does not provide a basis for allowing the sender to take credit for knowledge of the contents of the message.

So, whether this scheme is adequate will depend upon the particular application you have.  Many applications only need authentication for the purpose of assigning responsibility: if something goes wrong, we know who to hold responsible (or, we know whose account to charge or whose quota to decrement), and encrypt-then-sign is fine for that.  But a few applications (the password authentication example I mentioned; auctions; and some others) use authentication to additionally allow the parties to take credit for knowledge of a message.  For those applications, vanilla encrypt-then-sign can be problematic.

There are ways to fix encrypt-then-sign so it doesn't have this shortcoming.  See the research literature below for details.

For more details on all of this, including what can go wrong as well as how to avoid these problems, you can read the following detailed explanation in the research literature:

- [Prudent engineering practice for cryptographic protocols](http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~abadi/Papers/gep-ieee.ps). Martin Abadi and Roger Needham.  See Section 5.2 (but the entire paper is fantastic and a classic).
- [Security Protocols and their Properties](http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~abadi/Papers/nato.ps).  Martin Abadi.  See Section 5.

Comment: Interesting papers that I hadn't come across before, thanks

Answer (score -2):

Actually, Encrypt-then-MAC (EtM) is considered to be the most secure mechanism to achieve Authenticated Encryption (AE).
There is also a research paper by Mihir Bellare on this topic:
https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/oem.pdf

This is another resource from Dan Boneh's crypto class where the exact same thing is discussed (slide 29).
https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/courses/OnlineCrypto/slides/07-authenc-v2-annotated.pptx

Also, another link on using the EtM paradigm:
https://moxie.org/blog/the-cryptographic-doom-principle/

Comment: The question is not about authenticated encryption with a symmetric key. It's about a scheme where the signature uses public-key cryptography.

Comment: If the signature is using a secure algorithm then the public key / private key does not matter as the forgery attack on either will be similar.  The use of RSA does not have much impact if the EtM scheme is used.